# What is the difference between overriding or destroying the Control Towers?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn, horizon-zero-dawn-the-frozen-wilds

I've just started The Frozen Wilds DLC for Horizon Zero Dawn.  I've encountered some Control Towers, and have the option of either overriding them or destroying them.  Is there an advantage to either option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both overriding and destroying a [control tower](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Control_Tower) will disable the machine and choosing either option will award you a trophy after disabling them all.

Whether you choose to override or destroy, the key difference to keep in mind is that overriding the control tower will send out a shock wave that will stun all other machines that was under it's control for a short period of time.

Choosing to override the control towers is particularly useful

> during the errand [The Claws Beneath](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/The_Claws_Beneath). This errand has you face a  Daemonic Rockbreaker, which you can override the nearby control towers to stun it.